# Is there a way to disable message forwarding in a telegram channel?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have a private channel that is being used for sending paid features (in form of voice and sometimes texts and images) to selected members.

The only problem is that some of the users easily distribute my content to their friends (and, in turn, they distribute it to their own friends, etc.).

Is there a bot to disable message forwarding? Or even better, replace the forwarded message with a modified version that shows parts of the post (or a selected clip from the voice) as the message is being forwarded?

Comment: Folks can distribute even without forwarding. Telegram allow downloads. You should work on DRM apps. [learn more](https://www.google.com/search?q=drm+softwares)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, there is no way to do this so far. If you want to protect your content you may send web links to your private channel. The linked web pages would need providing username/password to show content. This approach will make it harder for your users to distribute your work, but it is still possible to save the files and send them from scratch. I don't think you can do much about it.